# Clean method that can intake one of multiple fields and modify it (C#)

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm wondering what's the "good" way to go about something like this (this is in C#):

I have class with multiple fields:

```
public class Actor()
{
    int Health;
    int Stamina;
    int Mana;
}
```

I want a method that can update those fields - in every case it would be "field + someVal" or "field -= someVal"

I could create a method for each field, but that seems like a lot of fairly duplicate code.

Likewise I could create a single function with a bunch of cases. But that also seems like it could be a lot of near duplicative work if say you have 20 skills that all need something structurally similar like that.

Is there a better way?

I was thinking of something like

```
public void LoseStat (string statName, int amount)
{
    statName += amount;
}
```

But of course this wouldn't work because statName is a string and not the field itself.

What is a good way of going about this?

Comment: How do you intend to call this? If you still need to specify the statName each time you use it, you haven't won anything (in contrast: you lost type safety).

Comment: You are going to have the same amount of code whether you use 3 individual methods or a single commingled one such as in the initial answer.  Its not very robust and not all that clear.  I'd opt for CLEAR (to wit: easy to understand when you come back to it 6 months later, and equally easy to understand the usage of) code that is also robust

Comment: Change private fields to public properties.

Comment: I also agree that you should have 3 methods.  1. This makes easy to understand and maintain code.  2. You can easily expand one the method later to include additional functionality such as validation/range checks without impacting the others.

Comment: @GuruStrong Excuse my ignorance, but how would that resolve the issue?

Comment: Or it may be more sensible to have `Dictionary<string, int> stats` as your data structure rather than separate fields.

Comment: it doesn't solve your problem, but it's good style to use properties when you need public access.

Answer (score 1):

Add switch statement

```
    public void UpdateStat(string statName, int amount)
        {
            switch (statName)
            {
                case "Health":
                    Health += amount;
                    break;
                case "Stamina":
                    Stamina += amount;
                    break;
                case "Mana":
                    Mana += amount;
                    break;
                // Add more cases for other stats if needed
                default:
                    // Handle unknown statName if necessary
                    break;
            }
}
```

Comment: That's my current implementation! =)

Comment: This is the cleanest one i can think other option is using reflection to find property name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ref parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#ref-parameter-modifier):

```
LoseStat(ref Health, 5);
...
public void LoseStat (ref int field, int amount)
{
    field += amount;
}
```

Or you could a class or struct to provide any helper methods:

```
public class MyStat{
    public int Value {get; private set;}
    public void Lose(int amount) => Value += amount;
}
public class Actor()
{
    MyStat Health;
    MyStat Stamina;
    MyStat Mana;
    public void Damage() => Health.Lose(5);
}
```

In the end the best solution will depend on what you are actually trying to do. There is probably not much value in replacing `Health += 5` with `LoseStat(ref Health, 5)`. My recommendations would be to avoid [stringly typing](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) and reflection, since this loses many of the benefit a static typed language provides. Try instead to create appropriate types to model your problem, i.e. avoid [Primitive Obsession](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession).

Answer (score 0):

What about reflection?

```
public void LoseStat (string statName, int amount)
{
    var field = this.GetType().GetField(statName);
    var oldValue = (int) field.GetValue(this);
    var newValue = oldValue += amount;
    this.GetType().GetField(statName).SetValue(this, newValue);
}
```

This assumes your `LoseStat`-function to be in `Actor`-class.

You should of course also handle the case, that a field doesn't exist, which is when `GetField` returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about reflection! That's cool to see!

Comment: @PaulAtreides0 in general you should avoid using reflection or at least "cache" it. But there are cases when it's convenient. But arguably nowadays most of them can be substituted with source generators.

Comment: With this solution, you should also add constants with the names of your fields, like `public const string NameHealth = nameof(Health);` and call your method with these constants: `LoseStat(Actor.NameHealth, 5);` Otherwise, you will get trouble if you rename one of your variables or if you have a typo in your string.